# An excel book opened from the shell doesn't see that other excel files are open

Tags: excel, shell, vbscript

When I open the file Book1.xlsm with a vbs script, it doesn't see that Book2.xlsm is already open, and this is a problem because the macro1 I want to run in Book1 does something different depending on if it is open or not. Is there a line of code to run in the shell or in vba to have excel fix this mistake?

Here is the code in the vbs file:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts=False
Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Test/Book1.xlsm")
objExcel.Application.Run "Book1.xlsm!Macro1"
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through line by line and pausing until the wb is fully open?

Comment: You could try [this](https://excel.tips.net/T009451_Finding_Other_Instances_of_Excel_in_a_Macro.html)

Comment: You need to get a reference to Book2. Try `Workbooks()` collection or `GetObject`.

Comment: Likely you are opening Book1 in a different instance of Excel.  If there's already a single open instance of Excel, try using GetObject() in your script instead of CreateObject()  `Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")`

Comment: Use `GetObject("c:\book2")` this will connect to any excel window with book2 or open it if not already opened.

Comment: Pardon the hammer here, the [tag:shell] tag should not have been applied here. Anyway, if you don't think the duplicate applies, please [edit] your question to clarify how exactly this is different.

Answer (score -1):

You can check all open workbooks and see if the name matches "Book2.xlsm", and if so, do something.

```
For Each Workbook in Workbooks
    If Workbook.Name = "Book2.xlsm" Then
        Debug.Print "Do something"

    Else
        Debug.Print "Do something else"

    End If
Next Workbook
```